# jQuery function parameters not working properly

Tags: jquery

I have the following script:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <title>Learn jQuery</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "CSS/style.css">
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "scripts/java.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id = "main">Click to Show and Hide <button id = "btnA">+</button></div>
        <div id = "box">Some content.</div>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#btnA").click(function()
                {
                    $("#box").slideToggle(2000);

                    // code block in question
                    if  (val == "+")
                    {
                        $(this).html("-");
                    }
                    else if  (val == "-")
                    {
                        $(this).html("+");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I wish to transform the `code block in question` into a re-usable function like this:

```
function toggleContent(target, contentA, contentB)
{
    var val = $(target).html();
    if  (val == contentA)
    {
        $(this).html(contentB);
    }
    else if (val == contentB)
    {
        $(this).html(contentA);
    }
}
```

However when I call `toggleContent("#btnA", "+", "-");`, it doesn't work.  Could someone point out my error?  TIA.

The suggested changes so far does not work, even the `DEMO`.  Could someone help?

Comment: Change $(this) to $(target)

Comment: @ArkadiuszG., it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Arkadiusz G**'s comment may give you the answer.

Change

```
function toggleContent(target, contentA, contentB)
{
    var val = $(target).html();
    if  (val == contentA)
    {
        $(this).html(contentB);
    }
    else if (val == contentB)
    {
        $(this).html(contentA);
    }
}
```

To

```
function toggleContent(target, contentA, contentB)
{
    var val = $(target).html();
    if  (val == contentA)
    {
        $(target).html(contentB);
    }
    else if (val == contentB)
    {
        $(target).html(contentA);
    }
}
```

UPDATE

And also add this

```
$(function(e){
$('body').on('click','#btnA','',function(){
   toggleContent("#btnA", "+", "-");
});

});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/r51wotLs/15/)

Comment: Wow!  It works.  Could you explain to me why it doesn't work it I just call `$("#btnA").click(function(){$("#box").slideToggle(2000); toggleContent("#btnA", "+", "-");});` in the main script?

Comment: It does on your demo, friend.  But when I put it into my HTML, it doesn't.

Comment: may be some other scripts stops it. do you have any error in developer console?

Comment: It says this: Uncaught ReferenceError: something is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (index.html:21)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.js:5183)
    at HTMLButtonElement.elemData.handle (jquery.js:4991)

Comment: i beleive `toggleContent` function is outside `document.ready`

Comment: Wow!  Thanks much, friend.  It's a reference issue.  =))

Answer (score 2):

Inside the function "toggleContent", the "this" object is not what you think, try this way:

```
function toggleContent(target, contentA, contentB)
    {
        var val = $(target).html();
        if  (val == contentA)
        {
            $(target).html(contentB);
        }
        else if (val == contentB)
        {
            $(target).html(contentA);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi if you want to convert it to function pass currentObj also to the function.

```
function toggleContent(currentObj,target, contentA, contentB)
{
    var val = $(target).html();
    if  (val == contentA)
    {
        currentObj.html(contentB);
    }
    else if (val == contentB)
    {
        currentObj.html(contentA);
    }
} 
toggleContent($(this), $("#btnA"), "contentA", "contentB")
```